# Android camera2api preview size stretches

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera2, android-textureview

I m trying to do recording using **camera2 api** in android and **my preview size stretches**.

can some help me why preview stretches

**here is my code:**

```
      private void setUpCamera(int width, int height) {
    cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String camId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
            cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(camId);
            if (cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }
            StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            //handling Rotation of the screen
            int deviceOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            totalRotation = deviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics, deviceOrientation);
            boolean swapRotation = totalRotation == 90 || totalRotation == 270;
            int rotatedWidth = height;
            int rotatedHeigth = width;
            if (swapRotation) {
                rotatedWidth = width;
                rotatedHeigth = height;
            }
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeigth);
            mVideoSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeigth);
            mcamId = camId;
            return;
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height) {
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
    for (Size option : choices) {
        if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * height / width &&
                option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
            bigEnough.add(option);
        }
    }
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizebyArea());
    } else {
        return choices[0];
    }
}
```

private static class CompareSizebyArea implements Comparator {

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight() / (long) rhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Stretches? What do you mean?

Comment: the height of an object is increased in preview than its original size